# Convert string containing HTML to actual HTML

Tags: python, html, string

**Set-up**

I have various string variable containing HTML, for one of them https://pastebin.com/rsi3v9nh.

I need to obtain the text inside the HTML. E.g. from the following HTML snippet,

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">\n<ul>\n<li>50.000 r.p.m.</li>\n<li>Dry technique</li>\n<li>Controllable by foot pedal</li>\n<li>Auto-Cruise</li>\n<li>Twist-lock system</li>\n<li>100W drill power</li>\n<li>7.8 Ncm torque</li>\n<li>220V-240V</li>\n<li>12-months warranty</li>\n</ul>\n</div>\n<p>[/vc_column_text]</p>
```

I'd like to obtain the text of all `<li>`s.

Note that this is just an example of a part of the entire string, the texts are not only in `<li>` elements.

---

**Problem**

Simply using regex will be quite cumbersome, because the patterns are a bit irregular.

I'm familiar with Selenium to obtain data from HTML, i.e. to do `driver.find_element_by_xpath('div')` etc. But this works only on HTML objects, not strings.

I was wondering if I can somehow convert the string into HTML and then obtain the texts in a Selenium-like manner.

Any other solution would be ok as well.

Comment: You're looking for an HTML parser.

Comment: You can use beautiful soup here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You definitely don't want to use regular expressions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3483203)

You can use [`beautifulsoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse this instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">\n<ul>\n<li>50.000 r.p.m.</li>\n<li>Dry technique</li>\n<li>Controllable by foot pedal</li>\n<li>Auto-Cruise</li>\n<li>Twist-lock system</li>\n<li>100W drill power</li>\n<li>7.8 Ncm torque</li>\n<li>220V-240V</li>\n<li>12-months warranty</li>\n</ul>\n</div>\n<p>[/vc_column_text]</p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
print(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

Output:

```
['\n', '\n', '50.000 r.p.m.', '\n', 'Dry technique', '\n', 'Controllable by foot pedal', '\n', 'Auto-Cruise', '\n', 'Twist-lock system', '\n', '100W drill power', '\n', '7.8 Ncm torque', '\n', '220V-240V', '\n', '12-months warranty', '\n', '\n', '\n', '[/vc_column_text]']
```